# Validate cell value ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to validate a value of an editable cell in ui grid, for example making sure that a password value is filled. I am using the event `afterCellEdit` setting the password value to the old value in case it is empty:

```
rowEntity.password = oldValue;
```

However, I'm not sure this is the best way to that, but more importantly, after doing that the row is getting dirty, and I would like it to stay clean so I won't save it.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me....try it..

```
gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
   //Setting old value here
   rowEntity[colDef.field] = oldValue;
});
```